# How to connect Arduino-Uno IOT recipe to MQTT over WiFi WPA

Tags: wifi, mqtt, ibm-cloud, arduino-uno, iot

This IOT Foundation recipe for Arduino Uno provides a way to connect to the MQTT server on Bluemix via the Ethernet client, but how can I do this using the Arduino Wifi shield with WPA secured wifi connection.

https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/recipes/arduino-uno/

Answer (score 1):

See this example:
https://github.com/remkohdev/arduino/blob/master/iotfoundation/recipes/arduino-uno/quickstart_with_wifi.ino

Use the Wifi package

## include

Set the WifiClient to the IPStack
WiFiClient c;
IPStack ipstack(c);

and then build your connection as in source code.